# Rules compilation error Drools action column, variable cannot be resolved

Tags: drools

I am pretty new to Drools and exploring the capabilities drools decision tables. I have downloaded Drools 6.2.0 examples and modified the one provided for decision table. In that I want to have policy condition to be removed as shown in image below

[image: Decision Table layout]

Here policy only needs to be result object but I am getting below error.

> text=Rule Compilation error policy cannot be resolved or is not a
> field

I am not sure what to write under first ACTION column to make it work as I have tried different values such as policy:Policy, Policy etc.

Below is the drl output I receive for the above decision table layout.

```
// rule values at C10, header at C5
rule "Pricing bracket_10"
    when
        Driver(age >= 18, age <= 24, locationRiskProfile == "LOW", priorClaims == "1")
    then
        policy.setBasePrice(450);
end
```

I have tried to check documentation but I was not able to find any way to make it working. Note that I have not modified anything in the source code of the example. Only the decision table layout in the excel is changed.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have an object of class Policy bound to a variable policy. One possibility is to insert a Policy object, and to have a pattern with it. The rule in DRL should look like this:

```
rule "Pricing bracket_10"
when
    Driver( age >= 18, age <= 24, locationRiskProfile == "LOW", priorClaims == "1")
    policy: Policy()
then
    policy.setBasePrice(450);
end
```

In a decision table you could use a condition column as show below:

```
CONDITION
policy: Policy()
/*$param*/
match a Policy fact
x
```

You'll need an 'x' in each row, or join cells to make do with a single 'x'.

Comment: I already have that in my code base where we execute rule from ksession. I am using decision table example and in the codebase I have not done any chance in the code. What I am trying to achieve here is that I want to have one object of input for condition and another to hold result value. But I am not sure how variables work in decision table excel.

Comment: The execute code looks like ksession.execute(Arrays.asList(new Object[] { driver, policy })); here driver and policy are the objects of corresponding types.

Comment: I have added the pattern for a column to match a fact without a constraint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but wasnt able to understand what to modify in the excel. Note that I don't want to have policy object's field in the condition, policy object is just used to hold the output only.

Comment: If you insert a Policy object as a fact, this is the best way to get hold of it in the then part. Or think of completely different ways of passing a result to wherever you need it, e.g. a DRL global, a static in a Java class, write to a file,...

Comment: Sorry @laune I am pretty new to drools and only explored the decision table part and I am not familiar with DRL global etc, from your comment if I add policy object in the action I need to have it in the condition part also to have it available as variable ? For all other options I will require to explore more on drools. As per your comment I think I can put one placeholder condition (with fix value) just to have policy as variable. As end users will not see excel in our solution I think its fine to have additional columns, what do you suggest ?

Comment: Did you check my updated answer?? I have added the single condition column that will give you the object with a variable bound to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86916/discussion-between-shaikh-mohammed-shariq-and-laune).